# facets not showing all the options drupal commerce

Tags: 7, commerce, search

Go to [this page](https://www.chellbell.com/products?search_api_views_fulltext=tract%20holder) if you take a look to the facets at the sidebar you will notice that they are not displaying all the available options.

When I search 1 word at the search bar for example "tract" then the facets work as expected, but when I use 1 or more words the facets does not display all the options... Does any body have had this issue before with Facets of Drupal commerce?

Any suggestions?

Comment: _Does any body have had this issue before with Facets of Drupal commerce?_ is a poll. Also, a question should not depend from an external link to be understood. Questions are also for future readers, not just the user who asks them; if the linked page changes, the question is not anymore understandable.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably set the filter in the view like this 
[image]